# New products list dedicated page

Tags: magento-1.9, category, layout, product-list, new-products

I need to display the products marked as new in a dedicated page in my e-shop and use the same products list template I am using in the catalog_category_view page. Does Magento already provide this functionality or should I write something custom?

Comment: what url would i go to to see this page on my store?

Comment: Dude I am also having a same problem? But is there anyway to add the "New products" to a specific category programatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_New`. so in your layout file you need to add something like

```
<block type="catalog/product_new" name="products.new" template="catalog/product/list.phtml" />
```

There's also a template for new products, called new.phtml (replace list.phtml with new.phtml) - depends on how you want to display things

Comment: what is the url for this?

Comment: url for what? that's a bit of xml code that needs to go somewhere in your theme

Comment: the url for going to the new products page i want to create

Comment: how should i know what your url will look like? i think you should look more into magento coding before implementing this feature...

Comment: i am familiar with magento, I want a page using the template of a category page displaying all the new products I am not sure what steps to take to get that i thought this was the question here

Comment: dude i am not getting this and really would appreciate some help, i need a category page with all the new products on it what steps would i take to create that page?

Comment: i tried creating a new CMS page and put  `<reference name="content"> <block type="catalog/product_new" name="products.new" template="catalog/product/list.phtml" /> </reference>` in the layout XML when i go the page i get this error "Fatal error: Call to a member function count() on a non-object in /chroot/home/mysite/html/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/tem‌​plate/catalog/produc‌​t/list.phtml on line 4"

Comment: yeah, because there's no product collection loaded. off the top of my head I'd say put this in the content of your cms page (and remove the layout update): {{block type="catalog/product_new" template="catalog/product/list.phtml" category_id="123"}} - replace 123 with an actual category id. A better option would be to use this widget: {{widget type="catalog/product_widget_new" display_type="all_products" products_count="20" template="catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_list.phtml"}}

Comment: you are correct there is no collection loaded `category_id="123"` does not help things any other ideas how to load the collection?