# A list page with new products

Tags: magento-1.9, new-products

I am trying to create a page that looks like any category page and lists all my new products, this seems like it should be simple what would i need to do to do this?
a similar question was asked here
[New products list dedicated page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/46427/new-products-list-dedicated-page)
I am trying to make a url that has the new products listed their, the question i have linked to does not explain how this is done what would i need to do to create that page?

Comment: That stack answer has the answer you're looking for. You need to create a block that uses type 'catalog/product_new' and you need to add it to your layout.

Comment: I am trying to make a url that has the new products listed their, the question i have linked to does not explain how this is done what would i need to do to create that page?

Comment: You can create that page in any number of ways with Magento. Either use a CMS page and add your new products block using the Design tab's layout XML, or add a new frontend route using an extension and add the block to it. The CMS method should be fairly straightforward- make the page in the CMS section of the admin, leave the content blank, and then use the Design tab to <reference name="content"> and then add your 'catalog/product_new' block.

Comment: so i created a new CMS page and put this `<reference name="content"> 
<block type="catalog/product_new" name="products.new" template="catalog/product/list.phtml" />
</reference> ` in the layout XML when i go the page i get this error "Fatal error: Call to a member function count() on a non-object in /chroot/home/mysite/html/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml on line 4

Comment: there is no collection loaded, any other ideas how to load the collection?